# State estimation of mobile robot

Tags: mobile-robot, kalman-filter, motion, movement

For a mobile robot - four wheels, front wheel steering - I use the following (bicycle) **prediction model** to estimate its state based on accurate radar measurements only. No odometry or any other input information $u_k$ is available from the mobile robot itself.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
      x_{k+1} \\
      y_{k+1} \\
      \theta_{k+1} \\
      v_{k+1} \\
      a_{k+1} \\
      \kappa_{k+1} \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    f_k(\vec{x}_k,u_k,\vec{\omega}_k,\Delta t) =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      x_k + v_k \Delta t \cos \theta_k \\
      y_k + v_k \Delta t \sin \theta_k \\
      \theta_k + v_k \kappa_k \Delta t \\
      v_k + a_k \Delta t \\
      a_k \\
      \kappa_k + \frac{a_{y,k}}{v_{x,k}^2}
    \end{bmatrix}
    +
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \omega_x \\
      \omega_y \\
      \omega_{\theta} \\
      \omega_v \\
      \omega_a \\
      \omega_{\kappa}
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $x$ and $y$ are the position, $\theta$ is the heading and $v$, $a$ are the velocity and acceleration respectively. Vector $\vec{\omega}$ is zero mean white gaussian noise and $\Delta t$ is sampling time. These mentioned state variables $\begin{bmatrix} x & y & \theta & v & a \end{bmatrix}$ are all measured although $\begin{bmatrix} \theta & v & a \end{bmatrix}$ have high variance. The only state that is not measured is curvature $\kappa$. Therfore it is computed using the measured states $\begin{bmatrix} a_{y,k} & v_{x,k}^2\end{bmatrix}$ which are the lateral acceleration and the longitudinal velocity.

My **Question:**

Is there a better way on predicting heading $\theta$, velocity $v$, acceleration $a$, and curvature $\kappa$?

- Is it enough for $a_{k+1}$ to just assume gaussian noise $\omega_a$ and use the previous best estimate $a_k$ or is there an alternative?
- For curvature $\kappa$ I also thought of using yaw rate $\dot{\theta}$ as $\kappa = \frac{\dot{\theta}}{v_x}$ but then I would have to estimate the yaw rate too.

---

To make my nonlinear filter model complete here is the **measurement model**:

$$
\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:bicycle-model-leader-vehicle-h}
   y_k = h_k(x_k,k) + v_k =
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x_k \\
     y_k \\
     \theta_k \\
     v_k \\
     a_k \\
     \kappa_k \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   +
   \begin{bmatrix}
     v_x \\
     v_y \\
     v_{\theta} \\
     v_v \\
     v_a \\
   \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation}
$$

---

**More Info on the available data**:

The measured state vector is already obtained/estimated using a kalman filter. What I want to achive is a smooth trajectory with the estimate $\kappa$. For this it is a requirement to use another Kalman filter or a moving horizon estimation approach.

Comment: May I ask what is the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Sure, i downvoted the question, because matrix oriented prediction model is based on analog pid-controller which are used in the 1930's before the first computers were invented. It is not state-of-the-art.

Comment: ok this may be the case - that it is not state of the art - but I think this is not a reason to downvote. As this "matrix oriented prediction" is still a possible approach which get's used frequently and I am required to use it.

Comment: "Not state of the art" is wrong.  The IEEE has 20 conference publications, 10 journal articles, and 8 other articles THIS YEAR that discuss both Kalman Filter and State Space control.  This is a proven technique that continues to find broad applicability for very challenging control problems.

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez is right that alternative solutions exist that may be more advanced (though his proposed solution is at best arguably the next candidate), but ultimately incorrect: the Kalman filter is absolutely still (begrudgingly) the state of the art in state estimation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is to use the following model with disturbance only at acceleration and curvature.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
      x_{k+1} \\
      y_{k+1} \\
      \theta_{k+1} \\
      v_{k+1} \\
      a_{k+1} \\
      \kappa_{k+1} \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
    f_k(\vec{x}_k,u_k,\vec{\omega}_k,\Delta t) =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      x_k + v_k \Delta t \cos \theta_k \\
      y_k + v_k \Delta t \sin \theta_k \\
      \theta_k + v_k \kappa_k \Delta t \\
      v_k + a_k \Delta t \\
      a_k + \omega_a \\
      \kappa_k + \omega_{\kappa}
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score -3):

Kalman filters and other state-estimation techniques are based on analog computing. In most cases differential equations are used. A better solution is based on grammar techniques aka turing-machines. A paper which is using context free grammars for state-estimation is given [here](https://www.ece.ubc.ca/~vikramk/WK08.pdf). The idea in short: the measurements are interpreted as a stream of tokens like a computerlanguage  and a parser interprets the sentences. To generate such parser motion primitive are used (simple Finite-States-Machines which describes a possible movement of the robot)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try to get some ideas out of the paper. Unfortunately the requeirements are that I use Kalman filters or moving horizon estimation.

Comment: You are welcome, the paper is a declassified version of the "Mercury context free grammar" for radar.

Comment: From the cited paper:  *The more traditional approach such as hidden Markov and state space models are suitable for target modeling [22], [23], but not radar modeling.*  I think the authors of that paper are solving a much more stochastic problem than you present.  If you do not have any other odometry from the mobile robot, then your approach seems reasonable.  You might be able to implement a feedforward model to account for friction, inclines, and other nonlinearities, but without local feedback even that would be a challenge.

Comment: This answer is not directed at the question, and is actually somewhat misleading.